# Localizable textual property names in resx

Tags: .net, winforms, resources, resx

I have a script that works with localizable textual properties in resx-files.
I am aware of the three of such property names: Text, HeaderText and ToolTipText.
Are there any more of such property names?

Answer (score 0):

While it not extensive list here something I used in my automatic localizer

"textfield",
                "groupingtext",
                "format",
                "filteredlisttext",
                "expandedtext",
                "emptymessage",
                "datatextformatstring",
                "dataformatstring",
                "customfilterdateformat",
                "customerrormessage",
                "collapsedtext",
                "expandedtext",
                "value",
                "tooltip",
                "text",
                "headertext",
                "name",
                "errormessage",
                "title",
                "alt",
                "headertooltip",
                "alternatetext",
                "entitytreetitle"

Comment: Thank you. But I am interested only in WinForms not in ASP.NET and only in property names of controls from System.Windows.Forms.